# ssl not working with MySQLdb but with mysqlconnector

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

unfortunately I can't get MySQLdb to work and neither connect via command line to an AWS server which requires me to use SSL. This strangely works fine via SequelPro.

## What works?

Beside the mentioned GUI, programmatically I use `mysqlconnector` instead of `MySQLdb` as engine and pass ssl args and this works:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

pd.read_sql("SHOW DATABASES", 
    create_engine(CONNECTION_STRING.replace('mysqldb', 'mysqlconnector'),
    connect_args={'ssl_ca': '~/Downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'}))
```

## What doesn't work?

For some reasons I don't want to use mysqlconnector but MySQLdb. Therefore I tried the following two ways:

```
conn = create_engine(CONNECTION_STRING)
pd.read_sql_query("SHOW DATABASES", conn)

conn = create_engine(
    CONNECTION_STRING,
    connect_args={'ssl': {'ca': '~/Downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'}})
pd.read_sql_query("SHOW DATABASES", conn)
```

For the first one it gives the expected access denied:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'MYUSER'@'MYHOST' (using password: YES)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

And for the second one:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2026, 'SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

From googling that "`error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)`" error I thought about misusing the package and made multiple attempts with various variations of basically (including `mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY`, passing the cipher) this:

```
mysql -h HOST --ssl-ca=~/Downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -u USER -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

throwing the same error.

## Ideas

Maybe this works on the mysqlconnector (without passing anything) because the `ssl` package (which is not used by the other both options I tried as far as I can see but definitely from connector) outputs on `ssl.get_default_verify_paths()`:

```
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='~/anaconda2/ssl/cert.pem', capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='~/anaconda2/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='~/anaconda2/ssl/certs')
```

, so there is some default configuration which makes this work (same for sequelPro probably). But all in all I just don't understand why it works fine with sequelPro and the connector package but not with command line nor MySQLdb.

Trying the following (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581284/what-is-the-equivalent-of-sequel-pros-just-checking-connect-using-ssl-in-mycl)) works fine:

```
mysql -u MYUSER -h MYHOST --ssl -p
```

But is not preferred due to the deprecation of the `--ssl` flag.

I hope some of you can see where I am missing something out!